# What is the longest comment thread of any SO question/answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

Does anybody know what the longest comment thread on SO is? By "longest" I guess I mean either the question or answer with the greatest number of comments in response to that single question/answer.

I know some people comb the data dumps to compile user rankings, etc., so I figured this knowledge might be out there somewhere...

Just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most commented post is of course the famous [html-cthulhu-regexp-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) with **114** comments

I computed [the result](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/95) with this command:

```
select count(*), PostId from Comments group by PostId order by count(*) desc
```

The runner-ups are

- [Since SQL Server doesn't have packages, what do programmers do to get around it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770300/since-sql-server-doesnt-have-packages-what-do-programmers-do-to-get-around-it) with **109** comments
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you/164556#164556 with **105**  comments

### Results for meta:

1. [Should I be discouraged by Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/should-i-be-discouraged-by-stack-overflow) with **64** comments
2. [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased) with **61** comments
3. [My God—it's full of unicorns!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicornswith) **58** comments

And let's add the SF and SU just for the kicks.

### Server Fault

1. [Need help installing a DNS on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/86170/need-help-installing-a-dns-on-ubuntu/86323#86323) with **36** comments
2. [Why is my LAN saying "unidentified network"? (Help setting up server architecture)](https://serverfault.com/questions/88309/why-is-my-lan-saying-unidentified-network-help-setting-up-server-architecture) with **29** comments
3. [HELP! Production DB was SQL INJECTED!](https://serverfault.com/questions/38549/help-production-db-was-sql-injected) with **27** comments
4. https://serverfault.com/questions/45734/the-coolest-server-names/45741#45741 with **27** comments

### Super User

1. [Fixing Windows install by connecting its hard drive via USB to a different laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/132599/fixing-windows-install-by-connecting-its-hard-drive-via-usb-to-a-different-laptop/132608#132608) **24** comments
2. [is it possible to access/write database ms access 2003 .mdb at the same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/77841/is-it-possible-to-access-write-database-ms-access-2003-mdb-at-the-same-time/77845#77845) **22** comments
3. https://superuser.com/questions/82036/recovering-a-lost-website-with-no-backup with **22** comments

The results are based on whatever version of data dump [the cloudexchange](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) happened to use currently.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the results for meta as well; we've had some quite lengthy discussions here, although a lot of the posts they are part of are later deleted by Jeff.

Comment: Great work. That last one is *crying* to have 256 comments.

Comment: @Ether, meta added

Comment: And also SF and SU

Comment: You youngsters probably don't remember the days of comment-flamewars in early 2009, mostly involving Rich B. I believe one thread hit 300 comments -- but the last 100 or so were just to see if anything would fail at the 256th comment. (Incidentally, I'll bet that thread is why there's a diamond-mod tool to delete all comments at once.)

Comment: @mmyers <waves hand> no there isn't.

Comment: @Jeff: Isn't what?

Comment: This answer is four years old. It says about 114 comments on [famous html-cthulhu-regexp-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1469208). When I'm opening linked answer, I see `show 46 more comments`. What am I missing? Where are the remaining 68 comments?