# What are the longest question and answer in entire SE network?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Can we have such silly questions here, on meta, or are they off-topic?

The longest one, I found is " [Are value converters more trouble than they're worth?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/114090/57759)". I know, that there are longest, which I haven't found, but I must come out with some example, right?

So... Is there any longer? What is the longest answer ever recorded in SE?

Comment: You mean _threads_?

Comment: Actually -- both. Longest answer and question in terms of size of text entered and longest thread of Q&A.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is poll, not a question

Comment: It would be a valid question if it was phrased as "how to find the longest Q&A" on SE? Data Explorer would be involved, then

Comment: The longest post appears to be [an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/181841#181841) in the formatting sandbox. [Run a Data Explorer query here](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/227861/longest-post).

Comment: [16K bytes](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/114090/57759), not too much. Even at Programmers, [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/108298/31260) is 32K bytes, and at SO, one of [John Fisher's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/50358/john-fisher) answers is even longer if memory serves. And that's only when you don't count pictures - because if you do, some of legendary answers at Super User, filled with multiple wonderful screen shots leave these bland plain-text monsters far behind

Comment: The more interesting search would be for the longest answer for the shortest question.  Long questions usually suck.

Comment: @ChrisF How this can be a poll, if there is only **one** answer to this question. There is only _one_ longest question in entire SE, only _one_ longest answer etc.

Comment: @all Some reactions here, at Meta, are just funny. This question has alrady gained 0 upvotes, 3 close votes and some negative comments, when [the very same question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49910/189165), only about longest comment has 3 upvotes, zero close votes and mostly nice, funny comments. How can the same question pattern bring so different reactions? You find my question off-topic. That one isn't?

Comment: Meta hates fun. It always has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Longest Question (185,343 characters): Meta Stack Exchange
[Should we get rid of all the tag synonyms which differ by only one or more hyphens?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147233)

Longest Answer (325,126 characters): Meta Stack Exchange
[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/181841#181841)

Longest non-Meta Post (72,769 characters): Code Golf
[Interpret Brainf**k](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/interpret-brainfuck/37887#37887)

At least for undeleted stuff.

<sup>Note: This is not an invitation to try to break these records, so please don't</sup>

Comment: See, I wouldn't have answered this for the very reason you allude to.

Comment: and of course the longest question *would* have been that tag one of Animuson's.