# Improve question management with GUI

Tags: feature-request, questions, guidelines

Currently, we have to query in the search box. It would be handy there's a search feature in every question category (i.e. categories like `summary`, `question`, `favourite`,...). There should be a GUI to make this feature visible, because when users don't see that, they may think it does not exist.

Also, when there are lots of favourite questions, it's hard to find the older favourite ones. Favourite questions should be allowed to have tags to make searching easier. The tags can be user defined when users add a question, or users can edit in the their profile later.

It would be more convenient for everyone if we don't have to type a query every time we want to search. New people won't have to learn the little query syntax just for searching specific things. This improves usability. i.e. if I want to search for something in my favourite written by author x, for language y, contains string z, I would just have to type "favourite x y z" and SO should automatically query everything that contains those strings, the top results are the closet to the query string.

Comment: You should brush up on the [Ninja Search Techniques](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching), which include specifically searching through questions (`is:question`), favourites (`infavorites:mine`). Combining these with appropriate tags `[<tag>]` helps narrow search results.

Comment: But it would be more convenient for everyone if we don't have to type a query every time we want to search, don't you think? New people won't have to learn the little query syntax just for searching in SO. This improves usability. i.e. if I want to search for something in my favourite written by author x, for language y, contains string z, I would just have to type "favourite x y z" and SO should automatically query everything that contains those strings, the top results are the closet to the query string.

Comment: Related: [Can we make it easier on new guys?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142104/168244) :)

Comment: Sure it would be more convenient, but the functionality exists using the current search techniques. Fundamentally the Stack Exchange network hosts a database of information, and the search bar acts like a database query, which uses a language users have to get used to.

Comment: We could easily provide a simple interface (a single textbox) rather than study SO own query language with those implemented features as backend. That's my feature request. Hopefully Stackoverflow devs won't overlook this.